# KDE dark themes with specific windows overrides

Tags: firefox, themes, kde

Is there any ark KDE themes that have a functionality to do what Oxygen can do - "specific windows overrides"? Or is there at least dark Oxygen themes or some way to make default Oxygen darker?

I tried a few dozens themes, but none of them didn't have this functionality. I need this to hide Firefoxe's title bar.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing Firefox theme? I use `FT DeepDark` with custom dark KDE color scheme.

Comment: You mean use dark firefox theme with Oxygen? No, it's not a way, I want a dark KDE theme either (Darcula theme in Intellij IDEA with light Oxygen looks terrible)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox - Dark theme in KDE (solved)

Well here is what I did.

1 - Type 'kdesu dolphin' in terminal.

2 - Navigate to /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

3 - Open firefox.desktop with Kwrite.

4 - Look down to the line - Exec=firefox %u

5 - Now place a # in front of that line or remove it, it's up to you.

6 - Now inset a new line exactly as below including quote marks;

Exec=bash -c 'GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Redmond/gtk-2.0/gtkrc firefox %u'

7 - Start Firefox, and yes it does look very plain and light when set against your dark theme, so in order to resolve this, I installed a Firefox dark them in my case NASA launch night.

Make sure the dark theme you have chosen is enabled. Restart Firefox.

Hope it helps
Steve

Comment: it has nothing to do with question